# Symfony 3.4 hidden field keep changing

Tags: forms, symfony, twig, field, symfony-forms

I have a form in symfony, and depending on a certain attribute, I need certain fields to remain unchanged. To do this, I mark them with

```
{% for calificacion in edit_form.calificaciones %}
[...]
{{form_widget (calificacion.fieldName, {'attr': {'hidden': 'hidden'}})}}
[...]
```

I have 2 fields like this, one with a number and one with a hyphen (pre-existing data). But when resubmitting form, it overwrites the hyphen with a blank space (because the user cannot enter any data as it is hidden).
I don't understand why the first column remains unchanged but the second one changes.

Comment: Can you show us more ? I'm kinda confused about what you have and your goal

Comment: Hi, can you show your controller? basically you can fill your field only on create.

Comment: If you don't want users to change the fields you can just exclude them from the form

Comment: The problem was (I think) that I had manually set values ​​in those fields. And these values ​​were not contemplated in the formtype. I added the hyphen in the type, and now it doesn't reset.